# Templates: how to generalize input to receive vector of ints, doubles or specific (template) container?

Tags: c++, templates

I am studying C++ through the book Principles and Practice Using C++, and have a question regarding one exercise. It proposes to write a `Number` class, through templates, to hold a number and overload its operators. Next, it proposes to use an also templated function to sum 2 vectors of different types (`int` + `double`, or `Number(int)` + `Number(double)` ).

My current code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class Number{
    T value;
public:
    Number() : value(T()) { }
    Number(T n) : value(n) { }
    Number(const Number& a) : value(a.value) { }
    T get() const {return value;};
};

template<class T, class U>
Number<typename std::common_type<T,U>::type>
operator+(const Number<T>& a, const Number<U>& b)
{
    return Number<typename std::common_type<T,U>::type>(a.get() + b.get());
}  

template<class T, class U>
Number<typename std::common_type<T,U>::type>
operator*(const Number<T>& a, const Number<U>& b)
{
    return Number<typename std::common_type<T,U>::type>(a.get() * b.get());
}        

template<class T, class U>
typename std::common_type<T,U>::type
sumProductOfVectors(vector<T>& vt, vector<U>& vu){
    typename std::common_type<T,U>::type sum = 0;
    if(vt.size() != vu.size() ) 
        return sum;
    for (int i = 0; i< vt.size(); i++)
    {
        sum += vt.at(i)*vu.at(i);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

vector<Number<int>> vni;
vni.push_back(Number<int>(1));
vni.push_back(Number<int>(2));
vni.push_back(Number<int>(3));

vector<Number<double>> vnd;
vnd.push_back(Number<double>(1));
vnd.push_back(Number<double>(2));
vnd.push_back(Number<double>(3));

vector<int> vi = {1,2,3};
vector<double> vd = {1,2,3};

sumProductOfVectors<int,double>(vi,vd);
// sumProductOfVectors<int,double>(vni,vnd); // Does not accept
}
```

While the function to sum the products works with standard vectors, I am having trouble to make it accept also `Numbers`. In the current form, the compiler indicates a no-matching call to the function `sumProductOfVectors`, when one of the parameters is from class `Number`.

How can one make it accept all types combinations of `vector<int>`, `vector<double>`, `vector<Number<int>>` and `vector<Number<double>>`?

Also, is a solution for this over-complicated, or having separated functions for this kind of problem would be more adequate and a better programming practice?

EDIT : reduction in code to improve readability

Comment: there is a lot of noise in your question. I had a hard time to understand which part of the code the question is about. I propose to remove all (but one) working functions that are not relevant to the question, to make the example more minimal/

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in the default constructor initializer list you have `value(T())`. That will copy-construct `value`, passing a temporary default-constructed `T` object to its copy-constructor. It's enough to do `value()` to default construct it.

Comment: Given that this question is about compiling `sumProductOfVectors<int,double>(vni,vnd);`, you should post the error you get from that in the question. Part of that error should explain which step of your algorithm isn't working as expected when trying to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more generic, your `sumProductOfVectors` may look like:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto
sumProductOfVectors(const std::vector<T>& vt, const std::vector<U>& vu)
{
    decltype(vt[0] + vu[0]) sum{};

    if (vt.size() != vu.size()) {
        return sum;
    }
    // return std::inner_product(vt.begin(), vt.end(), vu.begin(), sum);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != vt.size(); ++i) {
        sum = sum + vt.at(i) * vu.at(i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/p3hgAV)

Comment: should be `++i`

Comment: imho it would be good to mention that this can be done with existing algorithms and the code is (only) good as an exercise

Comment: @tobi303: `std::inner_product(vt.begin(), vt.end(), vu.begin(), sum);` added in comment.

Comment: @RyanP: Typo fixed.

Comment: @MarceloGaudenzi: Do you have C++14, C++11 or C++03 ?

Comment: @Jarod42 - I just noticed my compiler was set to C++11, thus giving an error in the `auto` return value type. I changed it to C++14 and your code worked without problem.

Comment: One additional questions: How would it be possible to mix different types, i.e. `sumProductOfVector(vector<int> , vector<Numbers<double>>)`?

Comment: `sumProductOfVector` should already work with that... if you provide missing `operator*(int, Numbers<double>)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For completeness of solution `operator+` also had to be provided. In this case, these operators should be also provided considering different order for provided parameters. 
Thanks you for the answer!